# How to use LIKE command inside SQL query of R

Tags: r, data-science

I'm new to R, I'm trying to use 'like' command inside R query but its throwing error...i'm attaching the code , please be kind enough to rectify the same...
let from i am passing med= ABC from API end..

```
med_aff1<- function(med,sex)
{
   affModel <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection ,
                  "SELECT * from XYZ WHERE MEDICINE %LIKE% %'",med,"'% AND SEX ='",M,"')
   return(affModel)
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting. what SQL language is your driver? probably `%LIKE%` shouldn't be surrounded with `%`, just `LIKE`. see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: You declare `sex` as a variable in your function, but you don't use it - instead you are using `M` in your statement.

Comment: @Michael i'm using it on R so the syntax is different i believe, please quote it for R lang

Comment: @KoushikRoy The syntax of the query-string not depends from `R` but from your database.

Comment: @jojo: thank u, but sex is a function argument being passed , it can be M or F, so i need to use the word 'sex' inside the query. should i go for SEX= ' ",sex," ' inside  dbGetQuery?

Comment: @Micheal.. i am using dbGetQuery, inside which im calling the sql query  from the function parameters,  so the pattern of query is little different from the usual sql command...pls help if u know how to do it inside R

Comment: @Andrew : ya i saw that, it should be '",sex,"' instead... please help me with the like command

Comment: @KoushikRoy I don't think your nested quotes are right - you need an extra `'` at the end. Try this... `dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection , paste0("SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE MEDICINE LIKE '", med, "' AND SEX = '", sex, "'"))`

Comment: @KoushikRoy And you should check the capitalisation of `XYZ`, `MEDICINE`, and `SEX` in your database.

Comment: @AndrewGustar.. I have checked with raw data , its running well, but my only prob is when I put the the function arguments and LIKE command...

Comment: @AndrewGustar ur code is not taking the like command

Comment: @KoushikRoy It would be helpful if you told us what the error messages are.

Comment: the like command in R is LIKE '%", med, "%'  AND AX.SEX ='", sex ,"'